# Running many instances of Rviz[for example] - ROS over Multiple machines

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

So, I am working on the project where different robots need to communicate with each other and I am using ROS over multiple machines. My question is if I run more than one instance of Rviz, say on different robots then all of the instances of Rviz will be publishing messages on the same topic. Also, different nodes will be subscribed to receive messages from the topics where their corresponding Rviz is publishing. But all this will create a mess because all the instances of Rviz will publish on the same topic and all corresponding nodes are subscribed to the same topic.
What is the best way to separate the topics on which different instances of Rviz are publishing so that corresponding nodes can be subscribed to corresponding topics?

I hope I have made myself clear. Please ask in case of any confusion.

Thanks in advance.
Naman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122111/running-many-instances-of-rviz%5Bfor-example%5D---ros-over-multiple-machines/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2014-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you should be using a separate topic for each receiving node, and configuring the corresponding rviz instance to publish to that topic.

I've seen this done in the past by assigning a namespace to each robot.

The tool properties in rviz have some support for configuring tool properties. For example, you can change the topic that navigation goals are published to.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1